# Infinity fetching loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Once I am opening my DocumentViewer fetching does infinity loop and I cannot see why this is happening, could somebody maybe see where is the problem, Its something to do with state and props but i cannot figure out why, it would be amazing to know what is the problem and how to approach it

```
class GeneralDocPresenter extends React.Component {

state = {
    metaInfoDocs: [],
    docs: [],
    loading: false
};

updateDoc = () => {
    this.props.selectedDocsStore.clear();
    this.props.selectedDocsStore.setViewDocId(0);
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    this.props
        .fetchMetaDocs()
        .then((r) => this.setState({ metaInfoDocs: r.data, loading: false }))
        .catch((err) => {
            this.setState({ loading: false });
            errorWithMessage("Could not load documents");
        });
    this.props.eventManager.on("viewDoc", (doc) => {
        this.loadDocuments(doc.id);
    });
};

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
    this.updateDoc()
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.updateDoc()
}

render() {

    return <Translation>
        {(t) => {
            if (this.state.loading) {
                return (
                    <div style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                        <Spin size={"medium"}/>
                    </div>
                )
            }
            if (this.state.metaInfoDocs.length === 0) {
                return (
                    <div style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                        <NoDocumentsAlert><div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: t('noDocuments')}}/></NoDocumentsAlert>
                    </div>
                )
            }
            return (
                <DocViewWrapper docs={this.state.docs}
                                metaInfoDocs={this.state.metaInfoDocs.map(doc => {
                                    return {...doc, type: this.props.type}
                                })}
                                eventManager={this.props.eventManager}
                                settings={this.props.settings}
                                childComponents={this.props.childComponents}
                />
            )
        }}
    </Translation>
}

loadDocuments(id) {
    this.props.loadDocument(id).then(r => {
        this.setState({
            docs: r.data
        })
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing `ComponentDidUpdate` from

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
    this.updateDoc()
}
```

To

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
   if(this.props !== prevProps){
    this.updateDoc()
   }
}
```

You can be more specific to didUpdate what to check instead of checking complete props change.

Comment: that works, thank you, could you explain in more details please

Comment: Right idea, but that inequality should always hold in practice. It's specific props or state that you should check for change

Comment: Ok, So what happens as earlier there was no check, as soon as render happens it goes to did update and find a function to update and it does and the cycle continues. So now when we have check it will see for any value changes, if there is change in value it will get executed or else it won't.

Comment: @Sohan thank you  so basically once render loads componentDidUpdate gets called and since its getting called fetch is happening and it continues doing loop since render always happens

Comment: Right. @ArtjomProzorov

Comment: Thank you guys for your help and explanation